# Spark Streaming + Kinesis : Initial record consumption

Tags: spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I'm feeding Spark streaming with a Kinesis Stream.
My project is using 1s batches,
during the first batches (the queue contains a few million items, and task is told to start from the beginning of the stream)
spark streaming start consuming batches of 10K records.
This happens every 10/20s.

i.e:

`t0 -> records : 0
t1 -> records : 0
.....
t10 -> records: 10.000 -> total process time is 0.8s (lower than batch time)
t11 -> recods : 0
..
t15 ->records : 0
..
t20 -> records: 10.000`

this beaviour occurs until spark cathces up with the top of the stream. After htat every batch will process elements every second.

It feels like at the start point it should consistently process a number of records per batch, without having htat high numberof batches processing no records.

Any setting that I'm ignoring? is the described behaviour expected?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you records flowing in constantly? It's unclear how exactly you're receiving them from your question.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I set up 1s batches, the attached images should answer your question (?) there is one kinesis receiver

Comment: Your images aren't answering my question. You say *It feels like at the start point it should consistently process a number of records per batch, without having htat high numberof batches processing no records.* But it doesn't work like that with Spark Streaming. If you send a batch of 10000 messages at once and it the receiver sees them and it doesn't have a *limit set* to it, it will consume them to their entirety.

Comment: Gotcha, by the time spark is started : 
(i). the stream contains a few million items
(ii). Spark is told to start from the beginning of hte stream (I force this by deleting the entry in the kinesis table)
(ii) sparks start consuming batches of 10K, but not consecutively, but in spaces of (10/20s)
hope the explaination makes sense

Comment: Kinesis might have some problem with start (TRIM_HORIZON) position. Also, how many shards are there in your stream?

Comment: actually this was due to a bug in the kinesis consumer in spark. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18620

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause for this issue is this bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18620 in the spark-kinesis consumer, which does not set maxRate correctly.